# HowTo perform XSLT transform on XML from TextArea

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am struggling to perform an XSLT transform in the browser using just html and javascript (I have tried many different ways and none of them work).  Here is what I want (and I just can't make it work).

1) I have an XSLT transform, I can make it available as a file (e.g. xslt), I can embed it in the HTML (I don't care), it is static.

2) I want the user to enter their XML into a text area.

3) I want the user to press a button and then I want the XSLT to occur and the result (which is html) to be displayed in a new tab.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And you would like us to help you with exactly ... what?

Comment: Show us one way that didn't work and we can perhaps tell you what you got wrong. That's usually more effective than asking people to write code from scratch. (Incidentally, if you want a more modern XSLT implementation than those provided by the browsers, with a simple Javascript API, take a look at Saxon-JS).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my own javascript to work.  Here it is for anyone who needs it.

```
/**
 * Load an XML document from server
 *
 * @param filename      filename
 * 
 * @return DOMDocument
 */
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {

    if ((window.ActiveXObject) || (!(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window)) {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
    try {
        xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"
    }
    catch (err) { } // Helping IE11
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}


/**
 * Text XML template: perform XSLT on user XML
 *
 */
function testXMLTemplate() {

    // create xml string from user xml in text area
    var xmlstr = document.getElementById("test-xml").value;
    xmlstr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + xmlstr;

    // load XSLT doc
    var xsldoc = loadXMLDoc("xml/paramToHtml.xslt")

    if ((window.ActiveXObject) || (!(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window)) {
        // code for IE
        var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
        xmldoc.async = false;
        xmldoc.loadXML(xmlstr);

        ex = xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
        var xmlTestWin = window.open();
        xmlTestWin.document.write(ex);
    }
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        var xmlparser = new DOMParser();
        var xmldoc = xmlparser.parseFromString(xmlstr, "text/xml");

        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsldoc);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmldoc);

        var xmlTestWin = window.open();
        xmlTestWin.document.write(resultDocument.firstChild.innerHTML);
    }
}
```